# Google Apps Script phone numbers from AD

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I’m trying to create a script in Google Apps Script that gets users' phone numbers from AD and copies them into Google Sheets.

```
try {
      if(user.phones[0].type = 'home'){
        prop.push(user.phones[0].value);
      }
      if (user.phones[1].type = 'mobile'){
        prop.push(user.phones[1].value );
      }
      if(user.phones[2].type = 'work'){
        prop.push(user.phones[2].value);
      }
      else{
        prop.push('');
      }
      
    }
      catch(err){
      prop.push('');
    }
```

Now that does work, but it puts numbers in unwanted cell order. It seems to type: ‘work’ ‘home’ ‘mobile’. Also, if the user does not have 3 of those numbers, so f.e. Only ‘mobile’, this script puts it first where ‘work’ should be. I was hoping this code would put them in a specific cell order: ‘home’, ‘mobile’, ‘work’. Any ideas?

Comment: What is AD?....

Answer (score 0):

1. Instead of `=` use `===`
2. The first two `if` hasn't and `else`. If you don't want misplaced data, then you should add `else{ prop.push(''); }` after each of them.
3. Regarding the order, you might have to create an Array of empty strings and replace the one that corresponds to each phone type by the corresponding value.

The following example uses `Array.prototype.forEach` and `switch` instead of several `if`

```
const prop = new Array(4).fill('');
user.phones.forEach(phone => {

  switch(phone.type){
     case 'home':
       prop[0] = phone.value;
     break;
     case 'work':
       prop[1] = phone.value;
     break;
     case 'mobile':
       prop[2] = phone.value;
     break;
     default: // This will manage other phone types
       prop[3] = prop[3].length === 0 ? phone.value : [prop[3], phone.value].join(',');
  }
```